# ModX getResources &tvFilters not working

Tags: filter, modx, modx-revolution, template-variables, modx-getresources

I have output from getResourses that I need to sort out by template variable value, but filter is showing resources that have only one value.

For example, this code is showing resources that have only `Manhattan` TV value.
Template variable input type is Tag, output type is default. I have tried to change the input type to Auto-Tag.

```
[[!getPage@Series?
&element=`getResources`
&parents=`[[*id]]`
&tpl=`New-series-catalog`
&limit=`0`
&debug=`1`
&includeTVs=`1`
&processTVs=`1`
&tvFilters=`door-color==Manhattan`
&tvPrefix=``
]]
```

[Screenshot of TV input options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5U4i.jpg)

[Output with intentionally broken tpl name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zle8e.jpg)

[TV value of resource that doesn't output, but should because it has `Manhattan` tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtcXL.jpg)

I have tried to use only English value names and changing search value to Russian value name but the result is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

**To filter by TV that has multiple values you need to add % % to the value.**

For example, my code should look like

```
[[!getPage@Series?
&element=`getResources`
&parents=`[[*id]]`
&tpl=`New-series-catalog`
&limit=`0`
&debug=`1`
&includeTVs=`1`
&processTVs=`1`
&tvFilters=`door-color==%Manhattan%`
&tvPrefix=``
]]
```

Instead of

```
[[!getPage@Series?
&element=`getResources`
&parents=`[[*id]]`
&tpl=`New-series-catalog`
&limit=`0`
&debug=`1`
&includeTVs=`1`
&processTVs=`1`
&tvFilters=`door-color==Manhattan`
&tvPrefix=``
]]
```

I hope that will help you so you don't waste time trying to figure out whats wrong.